# Addresses Delete not working in address book Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, url, address, delete

Add additional addresses to address book in magento 2.3 then Click on ' Delete Address' link in address book it redirect to 404 page and invalid url shows.

[image]

Comment: Hey @shafeel, I tried the same on 2.3.0, 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 versions respectively. I can't reproduce it. Can you check if this is not because of some customization on your part ?

Comment: Hi @Aparajit  please check Updated Answer..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below code in Delete.php file.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/Delete.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Delete extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
```

[image]

for more reference please [visit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19747)